# Issue removing cookie in browsers on iOS

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, cookies, mobile

Im running node backend and react frontend.
Since im currently using cookies to store my JWT, i can just clear cookies to log out. This works fine on my local computer, both in and outside of docker.

But when i host this on my server and access it on my iPhone, Im not able to sign out, i can use the phones browser tools and i can see the cookie gets sat when signing in, and the app is working fine to take advantage of the cookie for api requests, but for some reason im not able to sign out on the phone. I have tried both Safari and Firefox, issue persists in both.

What helps is using private/incognito mode, when i sign out there, the cookie dissapears and i get redirected to /login, but not in "normal" browsing mode.

on my phone, i can go to settings->safari->advanced->websiteData: Here i can see the ip of my server with 33mb, if i remove the entry here, the browser redirects me correctly again to the login page..

I also would like to add, when i connect phone to my mac to use safaris developer tools for my phones browser,
if i delete the cookie here, then just go to "/", it still redirects me to "/resources" instead of "/login".
The only way to fix it on phone without incognito is to either use the settings to clear the data or open a new tab. (On my computer i can clear the "authToken" cookie manually and it logs me out also.

My login flow is simple:

```
loginRouter.post("/login", (req, res) => {

/..Verifying login credentials../

res.cookie("authToken", token, {
              sameSite: "lax"
            });
res.send("Logged in successfully");

}

loginRouter.get("/logout", async (req, res) => {
  const { authToken } = req.cookies;
  res.clearCookie("authToken");
  /..Other user logout stuff ../
  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

React component:

```
import {useCookies} from "react-cookie";


export function Homepage(){
    const [cookies, setCookies, removeCookies] = useCookies(["authToken"]);
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const jwt = cookies.authToken;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!jwt) {
            navigate("/login")
        }else{
            navigate("/resources")
        }
    }, [jwt]);
    return <div>

    </div>
}
```

I appreciate all help, as i would prefer not to  move away from using cookies and rather include the JWT in an authorization header just for auth to work on mobile.